# Grouping removes (a lot) of lines?

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm very confused by the results I'm getting between 2 queries that I thought should be identical.

```
select count(distinct client_id)
from database1 a
inner join database2 b on a.client_id=b.client_id and b.year = 2021
```

and

```
select clienttype, count(distinct client_id)
from database1 a
inner join database2 b on a.client_id=b.client_id and b.year = 2021
group by 1
```

First one gives me 200,000 while when I sum all the clienttypes from the second one it gives me 300,000. And in the result from the second query, NULL clienttypes are counted (roughly 50,000 so it doesn't explain the difference anyways).

Any idea why those two are not the same? All I'm doing is breaking it down by clienttype, did I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have examples where `client_id` is in multiple types.

You can find these using:

```
select client_id, count(distinct clienttype)
from database1
group by client_id
having count(distinct clienttype) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that was possible within my database! (client_id should only have one type). That explains it :)